# What can Genji deflect?

Tags: overwatch

According to the [Genji Gamepedia page](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Deflect), Reflect's ability is:

> With lightning-quick swipes of his sword, Genji reflects an oncoming
>   projectile and sends it rebounding towards his opponent.

It's not exactly clear what this means. Does this mean that reflect can only reflect non-hitscan projectiles? Or can he also deflect hitscan projectiles such as S76's Pulse Rifle bullets or Widowmaker's shots? Can he also reflect Ultimates such as Roadhog's Whole Hog or Hanzo's Dragonstrike?

Comment: Now I'm curious if he can reflect Lucio's sound waves...

Comment: @Fluttershy You mean his BASSballs?

Comment: @Fluttershy [Lucio's sound waves can ***not*** be reflected.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309635/181240) However, his sonic amplifier primary fire can be reflected

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The list of projectiles **Genji** can reflect is nearly identical to the [list of projectiles **D.Va's** Defense Matrix can block](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309712/181240), but with the added bonus of being able to negate damage from Melee and physical attacks, such as **Winston's *Primal Rage*** or **Reinhardt's *Rocket Hammer***.

### Genji *can* deflect

- ***Ana's*** Biotic Rifle (scoped & unscoped) ([Source](https://youtu.be/0vd7w0v05wA?t=30)), Sleep Dart, and Biotic Grenade
- ***Bastion's*** Recon fire, Sentry fire, and Tank projectiles
- ***D.Va's*** Fusion Cannons and Light Gun Pistol
- ***Genji's*** Shuriken
- ***Hanzo's*** Storm Bow, Sonic Arrow, Scatter Arrow, and Dragonstrike (Arrow)<sup>1</sup>
- ***Junkrat's*** Frag Launcher Grenades, Concussion Mine<sup>2,3</sup> ([Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302481/when-does-a-reflected-junkrat-mine-explode/302492#302492)), and Total Mayhem ([Source](https://gfycat.com/BlaringFlakyAchillestang))
- ***Lucio's*** Sonic Amplifier
- ***McCree's*** Revolver, Flashbang, and Deadeye
- ***Mei's*** Icicle and Blizzard<sup>2</sup>
- ***Mercy's*** Caduceus Blaster
- ***Orisa's*** Fusion Driver and Halt ([Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_jW5iYq2zo))
- ***Pharah's*** Rocket Launcher, Concussive Blast, and Rocket Barrage
- ***Reaper's*** Shotgun and Death Blossom
- ***Reinhardt's*** Fire Strike
- ***Roadhog's*** Scrap Gun and Whole Hog
- ***Soldier 76's*** Pulse Rifle, Helix Rockets, Biotic Field<sup>2,4</sup> ([Source](https://youtu.be/lum-K9xgspg?t=45)), and Tactical Visor
- ***Sombra's*** Machine Pistol
- ***Symmetra's*** Energy Ball
- ***Torbjörn's*** Rivet Gun and Turret bullets
- ***Tracer's*** Pulse Pistols and Pulse Bomb
- ***Widowmaker's*** Sniper, Assault Rifle, and Venom Mine
- ***Zarya's*** Particle Cannon (secondary fire) and Graviton Surge<sup>2</sup>
- ***Zenyatta's*** Orb of Destruction and Orb Volley

### Genji can *nullify damage* from

- ***Reinhardt's*** Rocket Hammer ([Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4mt7i3/can_genji_deflect_reinhardts_melee_attack/d3y2zon/))
- ***Roadhog's*** Chain Hook ([Source](https://youtu.be/lum-K9xgspg?t=174))
- ***Torbjörn's*** Hammer ([Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/271508/can-genji-deflect-melee-attacks/271512#271512))
- ***Winston's*** Primal Rage<sup>5</sup> ([Source](https://youtu.be/Nhv1GVYPh3o?t=283))
- All character's standard Melee attacks ([Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/271508/can-genji-deflect-melee-attacks/271512#271512))

### Genji *cannot* deflect

- ***Ana's*** Nano Boost
- ***D.Va's*** Boosters and Self-Destruct
- ***Genji's*** Swift Strike and Dragonblade
- ***Hanzo's*** Dragonstrike (Dragons)<sup>1</sup>
- ***Junkrat's*** Steel Trap and RIP-Tire ([Source](https://youtu.be/EK8ivoi-4zA?t=131))
- ***Lucio's*** Sonic Amplifier (Alternate) ([Source](https://youtu.be/EK8ivoi-4zA?t=278)) and Sound Barrier
- ***Mei's*** Endothermic Blaster frost and Ice Wall
- ***Orisa's*** Protective Barrier ([Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_jW5iYq2zo)) and Supercharger
- ***Reinhardt's*** Charge and Earthshatter
- ***Sombra's*** Hack, Translocator ([Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291068/can-genji-deflect-sombras-translocator/291102#291102)), and EMP
- ***Symmetra's*** Photon Projector beam, Photon Barrier, and Sentry Turrets
- ***Torbjörn's*** Armor Packs
- ***Widowmaker's*** Grappling Hook
- ***Winston's*** Tesla Cannon, Jump Pack, and Barrier Projector ([Source](https://youtu.be/lum-K9xgspg?t=193))
- ***Zarya's*** Particle Cannon (primary fire)
- ***Zenyatta's*** Orb of Harmony and Orb of Discord

---

#### Sources

- [YouTube - ALL GENJI DEFLECTS by Oskar Overwatch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lum-K9xgspg)
- [YouTube - Which Ultimates Can Genji Deflect? by Arekkz Gaming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nhv1GVYPh3o)
- [YouTube - Genji Things He Can And Can't Deflect | UPDATED by Havvan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EK8ivoi-4zA)
- [YouTube - Fact Check: Genji Deflect vs Orisa by Rent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_jW5iYq2zo)
- [Can Genji deflect Sombra's Translocator?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/291068/can-genji-deflect-sombras-translocator/291102#291102)
- [Can Genji deflect melee attacks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/271508/can-genji-deflect-melee-attacks/271512#271512)
- [VG247 - These are the Ultimates Genji can deflect](https://www.vg247.com/2016/05/26/overwatch-these-are-the-ultimates-genji-can-deflect/)

#### See Also

- [What Attacks Can D.Va's Shield Block (or Not Block)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309712/181240)
- [What ultimates can be damage boosted by Mercy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309643/181240)
- [What do damage buffs affect?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309724/181240)

#### Notes

*<sup>1</sup>Hanzo's ultimate is fired as a reflectable arrow before transforming into unreflectable dragons.

<sup>2</sup>Only reflectable in mid air before hitting the ground.

<sup>3</sup>Junkrat still triggers mine detonation.

<sup>4</sup>Biotic Field is a projectile with no traveling speed.

<sup>5</sup>Primal Rage knockback still applies.*

Comment: Genji doesn't interact with the Translocator at all.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer My mistake. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Mayhem grenades can be deflected, but you must have your deflect up the moment the Junkrat dies. Was tested I believe in some YT's overwatch myth thing.

Comment: How is Halt triggered after a deflect? is it like junkrat and his mine? or does it have to hit a wall?

Comment: @ForceGaia I don't think Orissa can trigger it once it's reflected, but I can't be sure. Only tested it once or twice.

Comment: @deadinside I thought I remembered seeing it on Overwatch Mythbusters, but I couldn't find a good source. Do you think you can find the video?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro And your list may now be complete. [Genji Can reflect total Mayham](https://gfycat.com/BlaringFlakyAchillestang)

Comment: @Malco List has been updated with your gif. (Though I still need to add Doomfist's abilities)

Comment: Please note that [Gfycat](https://gfycat.com) will shut down on Sept. 1, 2023. This affects some of the media you included in your post since it/they were uploaded to Gfycat. I recommend that you edit your post and reupload the Gfycat media through SE Imgur to avoid losing them. You might need to edit the media to make it ≤ 2 MiB, which is the maximum file size allowed by SE Imgur. See [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16826/4797) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

From the evidence in this [video](https://youtu.be/e20-xxjGTK4), he can reflect pretty much any projectile except beams like Zarya beam, [Winston lightning](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4hn8vm/psa_genji_cant_reflect_beams_or_lightning/), Junkrat steel trap, and Mei frost, and Symmetra regular fire.

Therefore he can deflect hitscan and non-hitscan shots, as well as many ultimates, including Roadhog's and Hanzo's. When blocking Hanzo's [ult](http://youtube.com/watch?v=Gr422pwn2Ck), he can reflect the dragons as well as the arrow shot.

After the release of Ana, the projectiles he can deflect now include an un-scoped Biotic Rifle hit. Scoped hits and Nano Boost cannot be deflected (the damage is still prevented in the former instance). [Source.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=No2mH5_c494)

Comment: Can he reflect Zayra's alt fire which tosses plasma balls like Junk Rat's nade launcher?

Comment: @O-O yes, start watching from [here](https://youtu.be/e20-xxjGTK4?t=19) to see

Comment: This sounds like the same list of things that D.Va can intercept with her Defense Matrix

Comment: As a Russian, I have to correct that her name is ZaRYa, which means "dawn" and is a super-romantic name for the character :-)

Comment: @OrcJMR thanks for the catch. i keep misspelling it, because i mix it up with zyra from league

Comment: Actually, if Genji deflects Hanzo's ultimate-arrow, he _does_ deflect the dragons: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gr422pwn2Ck

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, hmm so maybe it depends on how soon or late he deflects. thanks for the video.

Comment: does the dragon change team correspondance by doing so? so could hanzo or his team get killed by a deflected dragon?

Comment: @Zaibis: The dragon changes team. Apparently there is also a bug when you reflect Hanzo's ultimate if he has a wolf themed skin on the reflected ult will be invisible

Comment: New to the list, Genji can deflect Ana's Biotic Rifle Primary fire **ONLY** while unscoped [(source)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=No2mH5_c494). He can prevent the damage from a scoped shot, but it will not deflect, and he cannot deflect her Nano Boost.

Comment: After the dragons appear, Hanzo's ult is not able to be reflected / deflected. Only the initial "arrow" can be reflected, and this will cause it to act as if it were cast by Genji's team.