# What Attacks Can D.Va's Shield Block (or Not Block)?

Tags: overwatch

What attacks and ultimates can D.Va block with her Defense Matrix shield (her E ability)?

Defense Matrix is supposed to block projectile attacks, so I'd be interested in knowing whether it can block the following:

1. Hanzo's ultimate (both in arrow form, before it summons dragons, as well as after summoning dragons)?
2. Zarya's Graviton Surge ultimate, while it's a projectile in-flight, before it "detonates"?
3. McCree's Flashbang?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Blocking Ultimates

According to [Furious Paul's D.va In-depth Strategy Guide](http://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/dva.html), Defense Matrix **will block most ultimates** in the game, including

1. Roadhog's Whole Hog
2. Soldier 76's Tactical Visor
3. McCree's Deadeye
4. Reaper's Death Blossom
5. Pharah's Barrage
6. Bastion's Tank Form

Defense Matrix will also block the following:

1. Zarya's Graviton Surge (before it detonates)

According to [PSA - DVA Shield Completely Nullifies Hanzos Ult if Directly Hit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/49hbey/psa_dva_shield_completely_nullifies_hanzos_ult_if/d0rz454), Defense Matrix will block Hanzo's ultimate both when it's an arrow (before it summons dragons), as well as after the arrow summons the dragons:

> The PSA is that unlike Genji's deflection which deflects the initial arrow but doesn't stop Hanzo's dragons appearing, the projectile-blocking shield actually stops the entire ult.

However, I haven't confirmed this myself, so I don't know how reliable that comment is.

### Blocking Other Abilities and Attacks

Also according to Paul's D.Va guide, Defense Matrix will not work on

> - All melee attacks.
> - All channeled weapons, including:
>
>   - Mei's Endothermic Blaster (short range freeze gun),
>   - Winston's Tesla Cannon,
>   - Symmetra's Photon Projector Beam,
>   - Zarya's Particle Cannon beam.
> - Lucio's Blast of Sound (alternate fire).
> - Zenyatta's Orb of Discord.
> - Symmetra's Sentry Turrets.
> - Roadhog's Chain Hook.

Defense Matrix will also block the following:

1. Reinhardt's Fire Strike
2. McCree's Flashbang

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've been killed by Hanzo's ult with my shield up a number of times. Perhaps I was at the wrong angle.

Comment: @DCShannon If you negate his Dragonstrike arrow before it turns into the spiraling dragons then you can negate the rest of the dragons.  If you try doing it when the dragons are already flying around, then you can't absorb it

Comment: "The PSA is that unlike Genji's deflection which deflects the initial arrow but doesn't stop Hanzo's dragons appearing, the projectile-blocking shield actually stops the entire ult." This is wrong, if Genji deflects Hanzo's ult arrow, Hanzo won't spawn dragons, instead Genji will.

Comment: Does it block Symmetra's Orbs? Other tank's don't but D.Va's is different.

Comment: It does block Symmetra's Orbs, but not her primary fire or turret.

Comment: Hanzo's Ult comes in two pieces. He fires an arrow, and a fraction of a second after it takes flight, it summons a spectral dragon.
If the arrow is destroyed by D.Va's shield before the dragon is summoned, the dragon is not summoned. Similarly, if Genji reflects the arrow before the dragon is summoned, it will reflect the dragon back.
source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/49hbey/psa_dva_shield_completely_nullifies_hanzos_ult_if/d0t4ud7
video: https://youtu.be/mZdS-TAm_Ao

Comment: @Wouter is correct. Additionally, D.Va is also able to block Mei's Q (Blizzard) if she contacts it before it hits the ground.

Comment: Does it block Roadhog's primary when he has hooked an ally?

Comment: An update gave D.Va the ability to block Roadhog's hook at any range.

Answer (score 4):

The list of projectiles **D.Va** can block is nearly identical to the [list of projectiles **Genji** can reflect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309635/181240).

The main difference is that, unlike **Genji**, **D.Va** cannot negate damage from Melee and physical attacks, such as **Winston's *Primal Rage*** or **Reinhardt's *Rocket Hammer***. I also have yet to test whether **D.Va** can block **Soldier 76's *Biotic Field***.

### D.Va *can* block

- ***Ana's*** Biotic Rifle (scoped & unscoped), Sleep Dart, and Biotic Grenade
- ***Bastion's*** Recon fire, Sentry fire, and Tank projectiles
- ***D.Va's*** Fusion Cannons and Light Gun Pistol
- ***Genji's*** Shuriken and Deflected projectiles
- ***Hanzo's*** Storm Bow, Sonic Arrow, Scatter Arrow, and Dragonstrike (Arrow)<sup>1</sup>
- ***Junkrat's*** Frag Launcher Grenades, Concussion Mine<sup>2</sup>, and Total Mayhem Grenades
- ***Lucio's*** Sonic Amplifier (Primary)
- ***McCree's*** Revolver, Flashbang, and Deadeye
- ***Mei's*** Icicle and Blizzard<sup>2</sup>
- ***Mercy's*** Caduceus Blaster
- ***Orisa's*** Fusion Driver and Halt
- ***Pharah's*** Rocket Launcher, Concussive Blast, and Rocket Barrage
- ***Reaper's*** Shotgun and Death Blossom ([Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/270428/181240))
- ***Reinhardt's*** Fire Strike
- ***Roadhog's*** Scrap Gun, Chain Hook and Whole Hog
- ***Soldier 76's*** Pulse Rifle, Helix Rockets, and Tactical Visor
- ***Sombra's*** Machine Pistol
- ***Symmetra's*** Energy Ball
- ***Torbjörn's*** Rivet Gun and Turret bullets
- ***Tracer's*** Pulse Pistols and Pulse Bomb
- ***Widowmaker's*** Sniper, Assault Rifle, and Venom Mine<sup>2</sup>
- ***Zarya's*** Particle Cannon projectile (secondary fire) and Graviton Surge<sup>3</sup>
- ***Zenyatta's*** Orb of Destruction and Orb Volley

### D.Va *can not* block

- ***Ana's*** Nano Boost
- ***D.Va's*** Boosters, Call Mech, and Self-Destruct
- ***Genji's*** Swift Strike and Dragonblade
- ***Hanzo's*** Dragonstrike (Dragons)<sup>1</sup>
- ***Junkrat's*** Steel Trap and RIP-Tire
- ***Lucio's*** Sonic Amplifier (Alternate) and Sound Barrier
- ***Mei's*** Endothermic Blaster frost and Ice Wall
- ***Orisa's*** Protective Barrier and Supercharger
- ***Reinhardt's*** Rocket Hammer, Charge, and Earthshatter
- ***Sombra's*** Hack, Translocator, and EMP
- ***Symmetra's*** Photon Projector beam, Photon Barrier, and Sentry Turrets
- ***Torbjörn's*** Hammer and Armor Packs
- ***Widowmaker's*** Grappling Hook
- ***Winston's*** Tesla Cannon, Jump Pack,  Barrier Projector, and Primal Rage
- ***Zarya's*** Particle Cannon beam (primary fire)
- ***Zenyatta's*** Orb of Harmony and Orb of Discord
- All character's standard Melee attacks

### Unknown

- ***Soldier 76's*** Biotic Field

---

#### Sources

- [What Attacks Can D.Va's Shield Block (or Not Block)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/269301/181240)
- [Does D.Va's Defense Matrix completely nullify Reaper's ult?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/270428/181240)
- [Overwatch Wikia - Defense Matrix](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Defense_Matrix)

#### See Also

- [What projectiles can Genji deflect?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309635/181240)
- [What ultimates can be damage boosted by Mercy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309643/181240)
- [What do damage buffs affect?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/309724/181240)

#### Notes

*<sup>1</sup>Hanzo's ultimate is fired as a blockable arrow before transforming into unblockable dragons.

<sup>2</sup>Only blockable in midair before it hits the ground.

<sup>3</sup>Graviton Surge only blockable in midair before it detonates.*

Comment: I'm fairly sure that D.Va cannot block (and Genji cannot reflect) a Widowmaker mine that has already landed, since it is not considered a projectile at that point anymore.

Comment: These have been really great answers, thanks for going through all these old questions today and providing all the complete info in this easy to read format.

Comment: D.Va main here. quite sure its not possible to deflect chain hook.