# Does D.Va's Defense Matrix completely nullify Reaper's ult?

Tags: overwatch

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/269301/140266) states that D.Va's Defense Matrix can be used to block Reaper's ult. [The Overwatch wiki](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Defense_Matrix) says

> For three seconds, D.Va removes enemy projectiles in a 15-meter cylindrical range in front of her. It also protects her allies. She cannot attack during this time, but she can still move.

Does this mean that if Reaper uses his Death Blossum while inside the cylindrical range, every single shot would be blocked? Even the ones directed in the direction opposite D.Va (the lazer would have to go through Reaper and not have LoS)?

Comment: Anecdotally speaking, I've blocked the entirety of Reaper's ult with D.Va when I was right next to him with Defense Matrix. None of my teammates died or took damage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what it means. Incidentally, that's an easy way to unlock the Shot Down achievement, which requires you to prevent 1500 damage in one use of Defense Matrix.

Comment: Ditto High Noon?

Comment: @Dallium Of course. Keep in mind that you won't be able to keep the Defense Matrix up for the whole duration, though.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Would this work through a light post as well? I assume it would not work around a corner but a light post, much like an enemy player blocks explosive damage even if the hitbox extends a decent amount beyond both sides.

Comment: This would work through a light post if the visual for the matrix extends past it. It's also worth noting that Reaper's ultimate only does 600 damage per 'target'. Has anyone tested if this counts Defense Matrix as the single target, or if it simply absorbs the damage per target that *would have* been hit by the AOE had matrix not been there?

Comment: I think (not sure I just heard from my friend) you can technically block hanzo ult also

Comment: @KimMinseo You can only block the Hanzo Ult if the arrow that starts it directly impacts the Defense Matrix. It cannot block the Dragon that is produced after it.

Comment: Someone should test and record video evidence of this.