# Can Genji deflect melee attacks?

Tags: overwatch

I understand that Genji can deflect pretty much anything, save for beam weapons and a handful of lethal accessories. Can he deflect melee attacks though? I've been playing more Reaper lately, so I'm at a much closer proximity to characters, and normally if a Genji uses his deflect I stop firing to wait. Can I melee him safely, so that I'm not just moving around waiting for his deflect to end?

Comment: Pretty sure his deflect will block them so that he doesn't take damage, but not actually reflect them. That's what happens for Reinhardt's hammer, anyway. Didn't make this an answer because I'm not sure about other characters.

Comment: I disagree @StevenVascellaro. No where in the linked question does it ask about melee attacks, but you took it upon yourself to answer it as such.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Fair point. I have retracted my duplicate flag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

He will nullify the damage from any melee attack with the exception of Dragonblade, but won't reflect it back to the attacker.

Comment: To add to this, Genji can't stop the melee attack of an enemy Genji using his ult Dragonblade.

Comment: So this counts for Reinhardt/Winston's Primal Rage melee attacks, as well as the punch/kick/gun-hit of other characters?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I have not specifically tested Primal Rage, but definitely works with Reinhardt.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf It nullifies the damage of Primal Rage, but not the knockback.