# Can Genji deflect Sombra's Translocator?

Tags: overwatch

Since Sombra's Translocator is physically thrown to its destination, can an enemy Genji deflect it? If so, how does it behave? Will Sombra still be able to teleport to it like Junkrat can detonate a deflected mine, even if it switches to the enemy team?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing happens. The teleporter just bounces off as if Genji wasn't even deflecting.