# When does a reflected Junkrat mine explode?

Tags: overwatch

Usually Junkrat can throw a mine that is triggered by the user.

If the mine is reflected by Genji when does it explode?

Is it user triggered and if so by which player?

Comment: I blew myself up once trying this yesterday with a friend :( (actually it was pretty hilarious xD)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's still Junkrat that triggers it.

If he sees a deflect he can (and should) choose to not activate it, but usually in the heat of the battle you click the button before realizing what's happening.